# Regex ignoring double quotes at the start of pattern to replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some trouble trying to make a regex detect the `"` at the start of the string pattern to replace, hope you guys can help me out.

So we have a legacy application here at work that returns some text that is used to generate a .ini file for another application. I don't have permission to change how that's generated so I'm trying to work around that.

My problem is that when I go to "View-source" as we use to do to get the data that we then  copy for the .ini file, the output is as follows for 3000 lines, each section containing a variable and it's properties:

```
[variable73]
  name=""
  number=1
  obligatory=1
  field="input"
  type="radio"
  value[]="Case 1"
  value[]="Case 2"
  label_value[]="2"
  label_value[]="7"
  description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Vivamus aliquam laoreet auctor. Proin commodo eu elit ac ullamcorper. Morbi facilisis malesuada augue id semper. Pellentesque commodo felis tortor, et tincidunt sapien pulvinar vel. 

    Phasellus sed nisl sed urna hendrerit ullamcorper non sed orci. Nam nec ipsum neque. Fusce erat sapien, aliquet vitae ligula ac, vulputate dictum nunc. 

Vestibulum non turpis elit. "
  idV="Which action was chosen?"
  codV="v8973"
  orientation=""

[variable74]
  ...
  ...
```

I need to remove the trailing blank spaces at the start of every line to get something like:

```
[variable73]
name=""
number=1
obligatory=1
field="input"
.
. 
etc
```

But without removing the blank spaces inside the `description`variable, because that mess up the text that is supposed to be shown in another application that receives this .ini file.

So I tried this:

```
$copy_contents = file_get_contents($url);
$treated = preg_replace("/\n(^\s+[a-zA-Z\n]*?)/m", '', $copy_contents);
```

And I got some sucess removing the blank spaces of every line, but that messed up the `description`, so I tried signaling the ending `"` and the line break as the start of the pattern, and I tried it on regex101.com and it seems to grab the right section, but when I try it on my code using:

```
$treated = preg_replace("/\"\n(^\s+[a-zA-Z\n]*?)/m", '', $copy_contents);
```

And this doesn't do anything. No blank space at all is erased, like it can't detect the `"` at the start of the pattern. Because it is HTML, I tried using the `&quot;` but does not work either way.

Can someone point my mistake here? Can't find a reason why my regex is unable to identify my `\"` in the inputed text.

Thanks in advance for any input. If you guys have an idea also how I can do this without deleting the blank lines between each new variable section it would be great.

Comment: What about just skipping the description? `description="[^"]+?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\n(^\s+[a-zA-Z\n]*?)`

Comment: 1. If you want to strip out the horizontal space before `var=` try [`^\h++(?=[^\n=]+=)`](https://regex101.com/r/tsrkC1/1) 2. For skipping any double quoted stuff, like @user3783243 recommend something like [`"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|^\h+`](https://regex101.com/r/tsrkC1/2) both fault-prone, depending on input.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:-

```
<?php

$copy_contents = file_get_contents("data.txt");
$treated = preg_replace("/(^\s+[\.]*?)/m", '', $copy_contents);
echo $treated;

?>
```

Output:-

```
[variable73]
name=""
number=1
obligatory=1
field="input"
type="radio"
value[]="Case 1"
value[]="Case 2"
label_value[]="2"
label_value[]="7"
description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vivamus aliquam laoreet auctor. Proin commodo eu elit ac ullamcorper. Morbi facilisis malesuada augue id semper. Pellentesque commodo felis tortor, et tincidunt sapien pulvinar vel. 
Phasellus sed nisl sed urna hendrerit ullamcorper non sed orci. Nam nec ipsum neque. Fusce erat sapien, aliquet vitae ligula ac, vulputate dictum nunc. 
Vestibulum non turpis elit. "
idV="Which action was chosen?"
codV="v8973"
orientation=""
[variable74]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to match the quoted values, but skip them
by using the verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.

This way, the quoted parts are skipped.

It's important to enclose the alternation in an *atomic group* `(?> )`
which doesn't allow the quoted clause to be ignored in favor of matching
inside the quote.

`(?m)(?>"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^\h+)`

https://regex101.com/r/AbhrVB/1

Readable version

```
 (?m)                   # Multi-line mode
 (?>                    # Atomic group, don't allow backtracking into this 
      " [^"]* "              # Bypass any quoted values. Match it but skip
      (*SKIP) (*FAIL) 
   |                       # or,
      ^ \h+                  # Match at BOL many horizontal whitespace
 )
```